# How can I convert a long long into an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to convert an integer into an array. My goal is to be able to take a long long, for example `123456789...`, and make an array in which each digit holds one spot, like this `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...}`.

I can't use `iota()` because I am not allowed to, and I don't want to use `snprintf` because I don't want to print the array. I just want to make it.

After thinking about it for awhile, the only solution I thought of was to

1. Create a loop to divide the number by ten for each digit, leaving the quotient as an int
2. Let the decimals of the quotient go away via the restrictions of the int data type
3. Make a for loop to decrement the number until it becomes divisible by ten, all while incrementing a counter `i`
4. Let the `i` effectively become the digit and pass it into the array

But I feel like I am making this extremely overcomplicated, and there must be a simpler way to do this. So, have I answered my own question or is there and easier way?

Comment: You want to capture the remainder and quotient after dividing by 10 each time. The remainder goes into the array. The quotient becomes the new number to divide by 10 the next time through your loop until the quotient becomes 0. Be aware, though, that you'll get the least significant digits first. So you'll need to figure out how to flip the order.

Comment: @lurker 1, 2, 3, and 4 are actually a series of steps. But, the use of a remainder would fix my problem. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @lurker Write it as an answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: do you want it with recursive or iterative approach ?

Comment: Do you care about negative numbers and `LLONG_MIN`?

Comment: @chux Only working with positive numbers

Comment: Suggest then  asking about `unsigned long long`.  It is a simpler problem to solve completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **iterative approach** for your problem which I guess works perfectly

The code below is commented ! Hope it helps

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // a will hold the number
    int a=548763,i=0;
    // str will hold the result which is the array
    char str[20]= "";
    // first we need to see the length of the number a
    int b=a;
    while(b>=10)
    {
        b=b/10;
        i++;
    }
    // the length of the number a will be stored in variable i 
    // we set the end of the string str as we know the length needed
    str[i+1]='\0';
    // the while loop below will store the digit from the end of str to the 
    // the beginning 
    while(i>=0)
    {
        str[i]=a%10+48;
        a=a/10;
        i--;
    }
    // only for test 
    printf("the value of str is \"%s\"",str);

    return 0;
}
```

if you want the array to store only ints you need only to change the type of the array `str` and change

```
str[i]=a%10+48;
```

to

```
str[i]=a%10;
```

Comment: Yeah, I was overcomplicating it. Thanks.

Comment: @chux It doesn't matter because I'm gonna rewrite it now that I understand the right approach to take.

Comment: @chux then perfection is unattainable in the first attempt !! I just forget to include the `10` by adding `=` to the operator `>`  ! now it works perfectly ! Thanks chux :) !

Comment: no problem @chux your comment is really useful ! Thanks again ;) !

Answer (score 1):

You can use only 1 loop :

```
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int number = 123456789;
    int digit = floor(log10(number)) + 1;
    printf("%d\n", digit);
    int arr[digit];
    int i;
    for (i = digit; i > 0; i--) {
        arr[digit-i] = (int)(number/pow(10,i-1)) % 10;
        printf("%d : %d\n", digit-i, arr[digit-i]);
    }
}
```